# AngularJS: What is the correct approach to update a resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I wonder what is the best approach to update a resource.

By *best* I mean the most common implemented, testable and which focus on AngularJS standards. What do you prefer, based on your experience.

Here are some cases I am thinking about.

#### Method 1: The easy one

```
var $scope.user = User.get({ id: 123 });
// get this object in a view form, change some stuffs, NOT all of them

$scope.doUpdate = function() {
  $scope.user.$update();
}
```

- Advantage: very easy to write
- Disadvantage: if it has a lot of properties and only one is modified, all of then are re-sent

#### Method 2: The copy

```
var $scope.user = User.get({ id: 123 });
var $scope.userCopy = angular.copy($scope.user);
// get this object in a view form, change some stuffs, NOT all of them

$scope.doUpdate = function() {
  $scope.userCopy.$update();
}
```

- Advantage: protects the `$scope.user` var if it is used elsewhere in the view or as a dependency injection; it is also possible to revert `$scope.userCopy`, to `$scope.user` if we want.
- Disadvantage: variable duplication and `$scope.user` will not reflect the changes.

#### Method 3: the very safe one

```
var user = User.get({ id: 123 });
var $scope.userCopy = angular.copy(user);
// get this object in a view form, change some stuffs, NOT all of them

$scope.doUpdate = function() {
  var userChanged = new User();
  userChanged.id = user.id;
  if ($scope.userCopy.name !== user.name) {
    userChanged.name = $scope.userCopy.name;
  }
  if ($scope.userCopy.surname !== user.surname) {
    userChanged.surname = $scope.userCopy.surname;
  }
  // and iterate on all the values we are expected to be modified
  userChanged.$update();
}
```

- Advantage: you know exactly what you are updated
- Disadvantage: can implies a lot of code and check, variable duplication and the `$scope` will not reflect the changes.

Comment: different methods for different situations...there is no `one-size-fits-all`

Answer (score 0):

I use a variation of Method 3, to do partial updates, and surely [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/) is here to help, I want to make sure that I only PUT the udpated fields, nothing more.

I define a diff function that pick the partial that needs to be sent to the server:

```
var diff = function(newVal, oldVal){
    return _.omit(newVal , function(value, key){
        return angular.equals(oldVal[key] , value);
    });
}
```

Before loading the form I have a copy of the current model:

```
var oldVal = angular.copy($scope.user);
```

Then the actual update will be something like this:

```
$scope.doUpdate = function(){
    var userPartial = diff($scope.user , oldVal);
    User.update({id: $scope.user._id} , userPartial);
}
```

And if the user hit the cancel button, or if something went wrong in the update process you can always revert back to the oldVal.